# Path transitions in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, path, transition

```
var x1 = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0,  markerz[0]])
      .range( [extentX, 0] ;



  var arrow = wrap.selectAll("path.arrow")
 .data(markerz).enter().append("path")
 .attr("d","M0,0 l12,8 l-12,8 m12,-8 l-30,0")
 .attr("class", "arrow")
  .attr("transform","translate("+ x1(markerz) +","+80+")rotate(180)")    
 .style("stroke","black");

d3.transition(arrow)
            .attr("class", "arrow")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+ x1(markerz) +","+80+")rotate(180)")
```

The transition does not take place.
Any pointers to where Im going wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're not changing any values in the transition.

Comment: Im working on d3 bullet charts like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961.                                       It works in the other elements like  var marker = wrap.selectAll("path.marker")
          .data(markerz);
 
      marker.enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "marker")
          .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down").size(130))
     .attr("transform",  "translate("+ x1(markerz) +","+0+")" );
  

         d3.transition(marker)
          .attr("class", "marker")
     .attr("transform",  "translate("+ x1(markerz) +","+0+")" );

Comment: Sure, but there the scale `x1` is changing. In the code you've posted, nothing changes.

Comment: Could the variable  `var arrow = wrap.selectAll("path.arrow")
 .data(markerz);` instead of the whole chain make a difference?

Comment: A transition animates value changes of attributes. You're not changing any values in the code you've posted, so there's nothing to animate. This has nothing to do with any specific variable.